# Error shows like "Object variable or With block variable not set "

Tags: vba, excel

While runing the below code I received an error on this line:

```
appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
```

The error is:

> *Object variable or With block variable not set*

A variable `sathish` should contain a value like `"ABC21A"`. Please suggest me how to declare this variable. Also, this code needs to run 1000 times to fetch data.

```
Sub macro()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim Y As Long
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, t As Long

    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim eRow As Long

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With appIE
       appIE.Visible = False
       appIE.navigate "website"

       Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
          DoEvents
       Loop

       appIE.Visible = True
       appIE.document.getElementById("Username").Value = ""
       appIE.document.getElementById("Password").Value = ""
       appIE.document.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click

       Number = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

       For Y = 1 To Number
           sathish = Cells(Y, 1).Value
           appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
           appIE.document.getElementById("filter_ReferenceCode").Value = sathish
           appIE.document.getElementById("filter_btnSetFilter").Click

           'Set IE = Nothing
           Set objCollection = appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")

           For t = 10 To (objCollection.Length - 1)
               For r = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
                   eRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                   For c = 0 To (objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(eRow, c + 1) = objCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
                   Next c
               Next r

               If t = objCollection.Length - 1 Then
                   Cells(eRow + 1, 1) = ""
               End If
           Next t
        Next Y
    End With
    ' Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Using `Option Explicit` I get the same "Object variable or With block variable not set" error here:

```
appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click
```

HTML:

```html
<span id="__tab_tabFilter" class="ajax__tab_tab">Filter</span>

<input name="filter:ReferenceCode" type="text" maxlength="32" id="filter_ReferenceCode" class="textbox" style="width:136px;">
```

Comment: You should really declare all your variables, and `sathish` should probably be declared as a `String` if it is going to contain values such as `"ABC21A"`.  (It's good practice to include `Option Explicit` as the first line of your module, so that your code won't run until you **have** explicitly declared all your variables.)  But that doesn't explain your error because at the moment your variable is declared implicitly as a `Variant` (with a subtype of `Variant/String`) so shouldn't do anything differently than if you had declared it correctly.

Comment: After `.getElementById("btnSubmit").Click`, does it navigate to different url? If so, you cannot re-use that Document instance. The error you got simply says there aren't those Elements on that login Document. You need to use a different method to get that new **Document** in order to get those elements. Search *ShellWindows* and there should be many examples.

Comment: ^^ or, if the `id="filter_ReferenceCode"` is on the same document as you clicked on the previous statement, perhaps you need to fill in its `Value` **before** you do the `Click`.

Comment: when i used F8 to run the code manually it working properly to get data. But i cant do it automatically use play button

Comment: Error happening here:-           appIE.document.getElementById("__tab_tabFilter").Click

Comment: How did your code compile with `Option Explicit` (which, BTW, you should **always** have), without `sathish` being declared? BTW you should give meaningful names to your variables: *your* name doesn't mean anything in the code.

Comment: If your code runs while debugging but fails when run straight through, that's typically an indication that you need to add in some wait time after certain steps.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your response, i use wait time now its working successfully. T